# Using Filament and stancl/laravel how can i put the login page in Central Domain?

Tags: laravel, filamentphp

The filament tell to do that

https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/getting-started#multi-tenancy

I follow the documentation, and the login page goes to the tenants subdomains. How can i put the login page in central domain and through a select field, direct which tenent I want to log in?

I put the 'InitializeTenancyByDomain::class', in the right places, extended the login page that the filament makes available to us and added the select field, however the login page is stuck in the subdomain and I can't think of a way to place it in the central domain and direct it, after authentication, to the subdomain I want to access.